# what's the correct way to build container images from openshift source code

Tags: image, build, containers, openshift

It's true that there is Dockerfile and target in Makefile. I only once succeeded to build image for openshift-apiserver, but almost always encounter following issue for many sub-projects, e,g, for origin,

> [root@host origin]# buildah bud -f ./images/hyperkube/Dockerfile.rhel .
>   STEP 1: FROM registry.svc.ci.openshift.org/ocp/builder:golang-1.12 AS builder
>   error creating build container: Error initializing source docker://registry.svc.ci.openshift.org/ocp/builder:golang-1.12: Error reading manifest golang-1.12 in registry.svc.ci.openshift.org/ocp/builder: unauthorized: authentication required

what's the correct way to pull those base images for build? There is not specific information found in project source. Any direction information is appreciated.

Comment: `registry.svc.ci.openshift.org` might be an internal hostname in a cluster. Can you add the URL of what exactly you are trying to build? Could you also add what you are trying to accomplish and why you are not using the OKD images directly?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. registry.svc.ci.openshift.org should be registry server for openshift.org, i once pulled a base image from it. While using OKD/OCP images directly is one way,  i want to build the images from source code, for the sake of curiosity and possible customization (after all, it's the nature of open source software). Origin is just a starting point, https://github.com/openshift/origin/. Thanks again for attention.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think going with a GitHub issue is the best way forward: https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/25080

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a trick. Dockerfile.rhel pulls images from registry.svc.ci.openshift.org/ocp/, which requires authentication, while Dockerfile (mostly) pulls images from registry.svc.ci.openshift.org/openshift/, which permits open access.

Comment: registry.svc.ci.openshift.org no longer exists!! elsewhere advertised as moved to registry.ci.openshift.org but the later always answers 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we have now to use:  https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/explore. Authentication is required and credentials are acquired via the creation of a service account at https://access.redhat.com/terms-based-registry/.

I was willing to rebuild the OpenShift oauth-proxy (https://github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy) whose original Dockerfile is:

```
FROM registry.ci.openshift.org/ocp/builder:rhel-8-golang-1.18-openshift-4.11 AS builder
WORKDIR  /go/src/github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy
COPY . .
RUN go build .

FROM registry.ci.openshift.org/ocp/builder:rhel-8-base-openshift-4.11
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy/oauth-proxy /usr/bin/oauth-proxy
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/oauth-proxy"]
```

which builds now with:

```
FROM registry.redhat.io/rhel8/go-toolset:1.18.9-13.1679486063 AS builder
WORKDIR  /go/src/github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy
COPY . .
RUN go build -v .

FROM registry.redhat.io/rhel8/s2i-core:1-391.1679483855
COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy/oauth-proxy /usr/bin/oauth-proxy
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/oauth-proxy"]
```

Producing a rather compact image, without being sure that I found the best equivalence... but definitely working.

Comment: more redHat registry changes ahead: https://access.redhat.com/articles/6999582?percmp=7013a0000034splAAA